# Angular JS pass attributes to directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, angular-ui

I have custom directive for datepicker. I want to reuse it in several different places. But in order to reuse current directive I have to dynamically pass and change different attributes into `my-datepicker` directive.

If you look inside datepicker.html I am using following attributes: `ng-model="departureDate" min-date="minDateDeparture" is-open="departureOpened"`.

Question: How do I set this attributes on the `my-datepicker` element level and pass all the way down to my directive html template? I want to achieve something like that:

```
<my-datepicker ng-model="departureDate1" min-date="minDateDeparture1" is-open="departureOpened1"></my-datepicker>

<my-datepicker ng-model="departureDate2" min-date="minDateDeparture2" is-open="departureOpened2"></my-datepicker>
```

Thanks for any help!

datepicker-contoller.js

```
app.directive('myDatepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/datepicker/datepicker.html'
    };
});
```

datepicker.html

```
<fieldset>
    <div class='input-group'>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="departureDate" min-date="minDateDeparture" is-open="departureOpened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
            <span ng-click="open1($event)" class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Datepicker usage

```
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <my-datepicker></my-datepicker>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <my-datepicker></my-datepicker>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j31ky7c2/

You can pass the data as well as functions as attribute in your directive.

```
<my-datepicker min-date="minDateDeparture2" is-open="departureOpened2" some-function="testFunction()"></my-datepicker>
```

You can receive this data in your directive's scope.

```
directive('myDatepicker', [function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        minDate: '@',
        isOpen: '@',
        someFunction: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
    }
}
}]);
```

Then you can simply use `minDate` and `isOpen` and `someFunction` in your directive template like:

```
<div ng-bind="{{::minDate}}"></div>
<div ng-bind="{{::isOpen}}"></div>
<Button ng-click="someFunction()">Click me</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! How do I pass function name from element level to directive? `ng-click="open1($event)"`

Comment: Use `scope: { functionName: '&' }`

Comment: @ItamarL. could you please give me example how do I invoke it inside my .html page?

Comment: @WildGoat, I have updated my answer to include an example showing how to pass a function to a directive.

Comment: @pravee-n, I've done exactly what you have said but unfortunately there are no event fired on ng-click. Could you please prepare JSfiddler example using `templateUrl` and `.hmtl` template file? Thanks!

Comment: @WildGoat I have updated my answer to include a jsFiddle.